# Adding an IF conditional into Google Sheets Macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm bringing some crypto price data via API into five different Google Sheets, and then I consolidate all that info into one. The problem is that the API fails sometimes and brings back an error code.

When that happens, I would like for the macro to avoid bringing the info from that Sheet.

The way I can check if the info on a Sheet is correct or not would be to compare a cell on that sheet, for example, if cell B6 on a Sheet is not equal to the text "head", the macro can go on.

This is my code so far, I just need to add the IF statement but I keep failing at it...

API-MARKETS is the consolidated Sheet, API-1...API-5 are the five individual Sheets.

```
function Consolidar_API() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
// API1

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API-MARKETS'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'API-1\'!A2:AD251').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

// API2
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API-MARKETS'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A252').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'API-2\'!A2:AD251').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

// API3
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API-MARKETS'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A502').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'API-3\'!A2:AD251').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

// API4
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API-MARKETS'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A752').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'API-4\'!A2:AD251').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

// API5
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API-MARKETS'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1002').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'API-5\'!A2:AD251').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Portfolio'), true);

};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
function Consolidar_API() {
  
  const meta = [
    { sheet: 'API-1', range: 'A2' },
    { sheet: 'API-2', range: 'A252' },
    { sheet: 'API-3', range: 'A502' },
    { sheet: 'API-4', range: 'A752' },
    { sheet: 'API-5', range: 'A1002' },
  ]

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API-MARKETS'), true)
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()

  for(let m of meta){
    const value = spreadsheet.getRange(`'${m.sheet}'!A2:AD251`).getValue()
    const check = spreadsheet.getRange(`'${m.sheet}'!B6`).getValue()
    if(check!==''){
      spreadsheet.getRange(m.range).setValue(value)
    }
  }
  
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Portfolio'), true);
}
```

If you expect the resulting value from API-* sheets to be numbers, you can use

```
if(isNaN(value)){
```

instead of

```
if(check!==''){
```

Comment: @MatO, have you tested the proposed solution?